# php missing string '%1800236%'

Tags: php, string

I have query like this below :

```
$str="SELECT * FROM table WHERE text LIKE '%1800236%'";
```

But when echo result like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text LIKE '00236%'
```

in case PHP version is 5.5.38. I can't figure out what error. When i run it in my localhost with PHP version 7.2.2 is just fine. i use postgres for my database.

thanks for answering my question.

Comment: View the source and what do you see? How are you building the string, and does the string come from a URL?

Comment: yes look at where the string is coming from.

Comment: not from url, i just write. I even write like this $ str = "% 20"; $ str = "% 12"; etc. but when echo result is empty. two numbers after the% missing with the symbol, regardless of the number. but when i write this "%1", "%3" is fine. is that bug of PHP for that version ??